# How to write an SQL statement that gets a row if the rest of the rows with the same userID are not a certain condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the following table:

```
userId |    State     |  Number
--------------------------------
 123   |   waiting    |   3
 123   |  processing  |   2
 123   |  completed   |   1
```

How can I get the row for a single user with `State = waiting` state given a `Number` (let's say `3` in this case) only if there is no row for the same user with a lower `Number` and is in the `processing` state.

In this example, the query would *not* return a row. If row labeled `Number = 2` was `State = completed` (instead of `State = processing`), then the query would return the whole row labeled `Number = 3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.state = 'waiting' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.userId = t.userId and
                        t2.state = 'processing' and
                        t2.number < 3
                 );
```

You could also use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(number) filter (where state = 'processing') as min_processing
      from t
     ) t
where min_processing < 3 and state = 'waiting';
```

Comment: That looks about right! Let me test it out and will approve the answer if so!

Comment: The `not exists` is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. I will approve the answer when it is available.